# How do you merge 2 JObjects in Json.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

Background: I am trying to serialize my data into Json and return it from my MVC controller and I want to merge 2 C# data objects into a single json result. I have overridden JsonResult to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject which works for 1 object. By I want to merge 2 C# objects into 1 json result.

Answer (score 2):

In Json.Net 4.5:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.FromObject(data, serializer);
JObject o2 = JObject.FromObject(data2, serializer);
foreach (var i in o2)
{
    o1.Add(i.Key, i.Value);
}
```

In Json.Net 6:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.FromObject(data, serializer);
JObject o2 = JObject.FromObject(data2, serializer);
o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    // union array values together to avoid duplicates
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
});
```

v6 source link: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/08/04/json-net-6-0-release-4-json-merge-dependency-injection